# Closing another tab/window

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, browser, tabs

I have 3 html pages. Page 1 links to Page 2, and Page 2 links to Page 3 (for simplicity).

I want the link in Page 2 to open Page 3 and close Page 1 (tab 1).

From what I understand, you cannot close a page with Javascript that has not been open with Javascript, which is where I get stuck.

I tried various bits of code found on the net, but it's looking ever more likely that this is not possible. Is there any alternative methods of being able to focus on an already open tab, or anything people might find useful for me to try please?

Page 1 is the main webpage, but after clicking the link in Page 2 I really want to be able to focus back on Page 1 - passing data.... I know that's contradictory to what I said above, but I was simply trying to use the 3 pages to test out some things with window.close() and so on...

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's not possible and it would be terrible if webpages could randomly close other pages.
If it's just for yourself instead of wanting to publish it for others, making a browser extension to do this might be a good alternative.

Answer (score 0):

As you say it is not possible to close a tab that wasn't opened with window.open. Perhaps you could display some sort of message or overlay to suggest the user moves tabs

Assuming all of your tabs are on the same domain you could try something out with a shared web worker [MDN - SharedWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SharedWorker) to detect which pages are currently active/

Note: cross browser support isn't great for shared web workers.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your first page is first.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>
        First Page
    </title>
</head>

<body>
    <button onclick="openWin()">Open Second Page</button>
    <div>
        This is first page
    </div>
    <script>
        var myWindow;

        function openWin() {
            myWindow = window.open("second.html");
        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Now your second page is second.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>
        Second Page
    </title>
</head>

<body>

    <button onclick="openWin()">Open Third Page & Close First Page</button>
    <div>
        This is second page
    </div>
    <script>
        var myWindow;

        function openWin() {
            myWindow = window.open("third.html");
            window.opener.close()
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

And finally your third page may look like third.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Third page</title>
</head>

<body>
    This is third page
</body>

</html>
```

That should work. Try this out.

Comment: This doesn't close page 1 though does it?!

Comment: Why not? You must open the first page. Then clicking on "open second page" will open the second page. And then you can click on "Open third page & close first page" and thus it will work. 
Note that your second page can't be opened independently. It must be opened via button click from first page. Otherwise this won't work.

Comment: But the first page was not opened using javascript and therefore it cannot be closed using javascript. Or am I missing something?

Comment: You don't need to open first page using javascript. You can open this independently. Just make sure that you have opened the second page from the first page by clicking on the button. And then clicking on the button from the second page will close the first page and open up the third one. Check out this gif for clearance. https://imgur.com/a/H3H8XUg

Comment: Yes that does work in chrome, but not in Firefox. Thanks for the idea though.

Answer (score 0):

It's written on the [MDN page for Window.close()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close) (emphasis theirs)

> This method can only be called on windows that were opened by a script using the `Window.open()` method. If the window was not opened by a script, an error similar to this one appears in the console: `Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script.`

So if your page 1 is not opened by JavaScript, there is no way to close it with JS by any means. I don't know of any way to circumvent this.